# SQL combining wildcard with variable placeholder

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard, placeholder

I am trying to change one of my **SQL** functions to be '`LIKE`' the queried field rather than matching exactly the queried field.

However, my syntax seems to be giving me errors.

Does the syntax need to change if I am using a placeholder?

The **SQL** query worked perfectly when it was;
" `WHERE SOUNDEX(f.foodname) = SOUNDEX(?)`".

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks a lot

```
" SELECT DISTINCT r.restpic, r.restname"
        + " FROM restaurants r"
        + " JOIN food f ON f.restid = r.restid"
        + " JOIN drinks d ON d.restid = r.restid"
        + " WHERE SOUNDEX(f.foodname) LIKE '%SOUNDEX(?)%'"
        + " AND SOUNDEX(d.drinkname) LIKE '%SOUNDEX(?)%'");
```

(edited: added picture of error)

The SQL statement is part of a Java/JSP project I am building, so this is the error:
[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XGKO.png)
[image: Screenshot of Error]

Comment: It _seems_ to be giving you errors, or it is giving you errors? If so, can you post the actual error?

Comment: `any ideas?` It took me a while to arrive at the impression that you do know what you are trying. I might help if you narrowed down what may be substituted in place of each question mark.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but still getting the same error. Would it make a difference if I removed the SOUNDEX function? I could live without it if it means the statement will run

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you intend:

```
WHERE SOUNDEX(f.foodname) LIKE CONCAT('%', SOUNDEX(?), '%' AND
      SOUNDEX(d.drinkname) LIKE CONCAT('%', SOUNDEX(?), '%')
```